# pipenv: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, ubuntu-14.04, pipenv

I am trying to install pyspark 2.4.0 in my project repository using pipenv. I am trying to create a virtualenv to avoid clash of library versions with various other projects.

On running the following command in Ubuntu 14.04

```
pipenv install pyspark==2.4.0
```

pipenv starts with:

```
Pipfile: /path/to/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python (2.7.12) to create virtualenv…
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python
New python executable in /path/to/.local/share/virtualenvs/services-6pEnYP44/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...
Complete output from command /path/to/.local/s...-6pEnYP44/bin/python - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 24, in <module>
File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
File "/path/to/.local/share/virtualenvs/services-6pEnYP44/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 581, in setlocale
return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2363, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 719, in main
symlink=options.symlink)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
download=download,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 918, in install_wheel
call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 812, in call_subprocess
% (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /path/to/.local/s...-6pEnYP44/bin/python - setuptools pkg_resources pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

**Traceback looks something like this:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(cli())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 717, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 249, in install
editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1724, in do_install
pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 565, in ensure_project
pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 500, in ensure_virtualenv
python=python, site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 901, in do_create_virtualenv
click.echo(crayons.blue("{0}".format(c.err)), err=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/delegator.py", line 146, in err
return self._pexpect_out
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/delegator.py", line 114, in _pexpect_out
result += self.subprocess.after
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found
```

pipenv fails to install the pyspark version with: **TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found**

```
pipenv version: 2018.10.13
python version: 2.7.12
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I had created a virtualenv in the parent directory where I keep all my projects. So i had a nested virtualenv sort of a situation. Removing the virtualenv folder in the /.local/share/virtualenv corresponding to the parent directory solved this issue for me.